# HTTP Header Referrer Cheating using PHP

Tags: php, http, header

I need to make a false referrer to certain pages using PHP.

In my http://www.**a**.com/header.php page I tried the following code

> header("Referer: http://www.**b**.com\n");
>   header("Location: http://www.**c**.com");

But this doesn't work, at least for Google Analysis. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Referer is an information sent **from the browser to the server** -- not the other way arround.

As google analytics has nothing to do with your server *(it works via some Javascript code, which is called from the client)*, there is not much you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change and compile browser source code (some browsers are open source of course)